# Infinite Cartesian Product: Understanding

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the definition of the infinite cartesian product, particularly with the intuition behind it.

According to my textbook, Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, the infinite cartesian product takes the cartesian product of each set $X_i$ for $i \in I$. This idea makes sense to me, but the definition of $$\prod_{i \in I} X_i = \left\{\left. f: I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\ \right|\ (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\right\}$$ does not.

For example, if I make a function $X = \{(1,\{2\}), (2,\{3\}), (3, \{4\})\}$ where $X_1 = \{2\}$, $X_2  = \{3\}$, and $X_3  = \{4\}$ if I take the cartesian product of them, don't I get $(2,3,4)$? How is this a function and how does it relate to the definition?

I am very aware that my misunderstanding most likely comes from an inadequate knowledge of cartesian products, and that my example may be incorrect. If so, please let me know what misconceptions I may have so that I can grow and learn!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X_1=\{2\}$, $X_2=\{3\}$, and $X_3=\{4\}$, then by this definition $X_1\times X_2\times X_3$ is the set of functions $f$ from the index set $\{1,2,3\}$ to $X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3=\{2,3,4\}$ such that $f(1)\in X_1$, $f(2)\in X_2$, and $f(3)\in X_3$. As it happens, there is only one such function:

$$f=\{\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,3\rangle,\langle 3,4\rangle\}\;,$$

so that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$, and $f(3)=4$, and $X_1\times X_2\times X_3=\{f\}$.

We don’t usually use this definition for Cartesian products of finitely many sets; by the more familiar definition we would have

$$X_1\times X_2\times X_3=\{\langle 2,3,4\rangle\}\;,$$

a set with one member, the ordered triple $\langle 2,3,4\rangle$. But the difference is mostly cosmetic. The ordered triple with which you’re familiar is simply a way of specifying to which factor set each component belongs: if $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle\in X_1\times X_2\times X_3$, we know that $x_1\in X_1$, $x_2\in X_2$, and $x_3\in X_3$. The functions in Enderton’s definition<sup>1</sup> do the same thing: they associate an element of each factor set with an identifier of that set, namely, its index, so that even if all of the factors are the same set, we can tell which ‘component’ comes from which factor. You might notice that when we write an ordered triple as $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$, we’re really doing the same thing, albeit in slightly different format, as writing it $\langle x(1),x(2),x(3)\rangle$, as if were an ordered list of the outputs of some function $f$ on the index set $\{1,2,3\}$.

In fact, there are actually several ways to define ordered triples, and one of them is precisely Enderton’s definition of elements of a Cartesian product: by that definition the ordered triple $\langle 2,3,4\rangle$ **is** the function $f$ above. If one is using that definition of ordered triple, there is literally no difference between the Cartesian products with finitely many factors that you’ve seen before and these with infinitely many factors.

You’ve also probably seen some infinite Cartesian products in another setting: the product $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, i.e., $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$, where each $X_n=\Bbb R$, is just the set of infinite sequences of real numbers: each $x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle x_0,x_1,\ldots\rangle$ of real numbers, which formally is simply a function

$$x:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R:n\mapsto x_n\;.$$

We could just as well write the terms of the sequence $x(n)$, emphasizing the functional nature of the sequence as an element of a Cartesian product, instead of as $x_n$. Either way, the $n$ identifies the factor $X_n$ of the product, the factor from which the term $x_n$ or $x(n)$ comes.

<sup>1</sup> It’s not really Enderton’s definition: it’s standard.

Comment: Wow! This makes a lot more sense now! My only question is the idea of the set of ordered pairs being the same as the triple. I understand it much better intuitively but how might we convert from one to the other? If we have any n-tuple, can we always construct a set of ordered pairs it's equivalent to as long as we have the index?

Comment: @mijucik: Ordered $n$-tuples by default give you the index set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$: you can always think of $\langle x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ as a function from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to some set such that $x(1)=x_1$, $x(2)=x_2$, and so on up to $x(n)=x_n$. When you’re dealing with products of infinitely many factors, though, you might not have an index set that you can easily use to list the components of an element of the product. You can still do it with sequences, but what if you have $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, for instance, i.e., $\prod_{i\in\Bbb R}X_i$, where each $X_i=\Bbb R$? Then it’s hard, ...

Comment: ... if not impossible, to visualize a point of the product as a list of coordinates, but it’s not so hard to think of it as a function $f$ that simply picks out $f(i)$ as the coordinate on the $i$-th factor.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot more sense. On a final note, is this definition of a n-tuple standard? In Enderton, $(x,y,z) = ((x,y),z)$ and so on until you get the set from the Kuratowski definition. How does this definition relate to the idea of the index set?

Comment: @mijucik: Enderton’s is one of the two most common, the other being to associate to the right instead, so that $\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle x,\langle y,z\rangle\rangle$; these are convenient when one is developing building up set theory axiomatically, but they don’t extend to products with infinitely many factors. The relationship with the function version is more conceptual than anything else: both are simply ways to identify to which factor each component belongs.

Comment: Wow! I see! I remember now that the basis for the definition of the ordered pair and ordered triple is that the coordinates of two equal ordered pairs are equal! That makes the idea of indexing a lot easier to understand. The problem is that axiomatically, how is $\{(2,3,4)\}$ the same as the set of ordered pairs we described above? If we use the formal definition without any form of indexes, how would this definition make sense at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108435/discussion-between-mijucik-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: Everything Brian M. Scott writes is worth reading! very insightful indeed

Comment: @Theoneandonly: I’d not go *that* far: I do have my share of mental hiccups too!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's look at your example. If $X_1 = \{2\}$, $X_2 = \{3\}$, and $X_3 = \{4\}$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^3 X_i = \{2,3,4\}$. Thus, $\prod_{i=1}^3 X_i$ is (by definition)
$$\{f : \{1,2,3\} \to \{2,3,4\} \mid \forall i \in \{1,2,3\} (f(i) \in X_i)\}.$$
Importantly, the set $X = \{(1,\{2\}), (2, \{3\}), (3,\{4\})\}$ that you wrote down is *not* an example of an element of this cartesian product! You should review the definition of function: every element of a function is an ordered pair, where the first thing in the ordered pair is an element of the domain of the function, and the second thing in the ordered pair is an element of the codomain of the function. The issue here is that the $(1,\{2\})$ (for example) is not such a pair: the first thing in this ordered pair ($1$) is indeed an element of the indexing set $\{1,2,3\}$, but the second thing in this ordered pair ($\{2\}$) is **not** an element of the codomain $\bigcup_{i=1}^3 X_i = \{2,3,4\}$ (it is a subset of $\{2,3,4\}$, but of course that's not the same thing!)

The cartesian product of these three sets would be written (in shorthand) as $\{(2,3,4)\}$ (**not** just the element $(2,3,4)$!), but of course the technical definition you gave says that the cartesian product actually is a set of functions. The actual set of functions $\prod_{i=1}^3 X_i$ will still have exactly one element, though, and $(2,3,4)$ is just shorthand for this unique element (which is a function).

Can you try to write out more precisely what this function is, as a set of ordered pairs?

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me clarify some misconceptions I had!

Comment: And also, the set of ordered pairs is $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$.

Comment: Yes, nice! [character limit]